# Elastic Search Processing Search Result

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I can run a search like the following,

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/cms-2016-03-30/job/_search?pretty=true&size=1000' -d '{ "_source":"DESIRED_CMSDataset"}'
```

which gives results like

```
{
      "_index" : "cms-2016-03-30",
      "_type" : "job",
      "_id" : "crab3-7@vocms0114.cern.ch#6472621.0#1459313328",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "DESIRED_CMSDataset" : "/BTagCSV/Run2015D-16Dec2015-v1/MINIAOD"
      }
    }
```

I would like to process this result to only get the MINIAOD part of the DESIRED_CMSDataset string. Various tokenizers exist, but I can't figure out the syntax for any of them.

EDIT:

If you can alternatively tell me how to do this at index time (precisely), that is an acceptable answer. I mostly need the syntax. I don't understand the ElasticSearch syntax

EDIT:

[This](https://qbox.io/blog/an-introduction-to-ngrams-in-elasticsearch) explains how to do this, but only applies upon the creation of the index. Learning how to do this by updating the index would be ideal.

Comment: That's something you could very easily do at indexing time, where you'd split the string on the `/` character and only index the last element of the resulting array. The bottom line is that anything you can do at indexing time, you should do. Otherwise, you can also simply get the `DESIRED_CMSDataset` field from the response, split it on `/` and only take the last token.

Comment: Could you please explain how? I have yet to figure that out. The syntax is very confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I have found to complete any goal is to use Kibana to make a nice data table. Set up the goal, and then find the ElasticSearch code that Kibana would use to get the data bottom of main frame in Kibana visualization tool).

This is the easiest way to program Elastic Search!! Otherwise you will literally spend days trying to figure out the syntax of the ElasticSearch query language!! Then, do youself a favor and process the resulting JSON in Python ...